# how to get highest integer value from mysql table PHP

Tags: php, mysql

how to get highest integer value from mysql table PHP

```
   $getingstoredata=mysql_query('select number from number ');

   while ($getstd=mysql_fetch_row($getingstoredata)){

   print_r($getstd);
                                                    }
```

and table stricture is same like this image http://fastcoding.tk/table.png

i want to display highest integer value for example it 120 is highest value in this table

Comment: `SELECT MAX(number) FROM number;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use MAX()

```
SELECT MAX(number) FROM number
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the Aggregate Functions.
SELECT MAX(field_name) FROM table_name GROUP BY field_name;

You can also use "order by" clause with DESC and fetch the first row from result-set.

Answer (score 1):

```
select MAX(number) from number;
```

Answer (score 1):

MAX() should serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

If your field is a **mixed varchar** where some values begin with letters, you can use this solution:

```
SELECT max(number) FROM table WHERE number REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

1. the function max() will take the highest value
2. the regex sorts out every value that not begins with a number

Answer (score -1):

```
$hinteger=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(integer) FROM number");
```